コンパイルエラーになるはずなのにeclipseでコンパイルエラーにならず、正常に結果が出力されてしまいます
JavaGold黒本に載っていた問題なのですが、以下のコードを書いたら非staticなInnerクラスでstaticフィールド(message)を宣言しているためコンパイルエラーになるとのことです。
しかし、eclipseでコードを書いてみたらコンパイルエラーにならず、正常にHello, Javaが出力されます。
なぜeclipseでコンパイルエラーにならないのでしょうか。リフレッシュをしたりeclipseを開きなおしたりしましたが変わらずエラーにはなりませんでした。
public class Outer {

    void test() {
        Inner.message = "Hello, Java";
    }
    
    class Inner{
        private static String message;
        public void test() {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.test();
        outer.new Inner().test();
    }
}


Java については詳しくないので回答はできませんが、"JavaGold 黒本" で検索すると以下のような批判記事がヒットします。 staticで修飾されたネストしたクラスのメンバへのアクセス | Java Goldの黒本に対する批判

回答については上記コメントのリンクにあるように「コンパイルエラーにならないのが正常で本の方が間違っている」で、これは直接の回答では無いのですが、そもそもこの「JavaGold」という資格にどれだけ意味があるのかが疑問です。以下の記事( https://qiita.com/ebichan_88/items/a2b526c3e206ed573ec4 )でも"上司の反応「資格を取ったのはすごいけど、学んだことをどう価値発揮出来たかが大事だよね」"で、英語で検索しても「評価」以前にそもそもほとんどヒットしません https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&q=java%20gold%20oracle https://www.quora.com/search?q=java%20gold%20&type=question

@cubick さん
コメントありがとうございます。参考書が間違っている可能性があるということですね。発行元に問い合わせることも検討しようと思います。

@Lamron さん
コメントありがとうございます。Javaについて深く知りつつJava Goldを取得したいなと考えています。コーディングの資格を取得したほうが開発側に推薦されるかなって・・・思いまして・・・（ずっとテストを任されているので）

ただの感想ですが、回答のとおりなのだとすると、書籍名にJavaの対応版数が明記されているように見えるし、Gold黒本 だとしたらまだ最新は 11 だと思われるので、内容としては正しいのかも？ オラクル認定資格の書籍一覧 「徹底攻略Java SE 17 Silver問題集［1Z0-825］対応」にそうした記述があるのならば改定してもらうのは正しいのでしょうが。

@kunif
そうですね。Java SE11なのでこの参考書は間違っていなかったです。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

解決しました。Java16の新機能としてインナークラスでstaticメンバが宣言できるようになったようです。
Inner ClassでStaticメンバーの定義 | Java 16 新機能まとめ - Qiita

@kunif さんの指摘にあるようにJava 11で試したところ確かにエラーが出たので、「Java 11」ではコンパイルエラーになる、が正しいようです。すみません。ただ資格を取るなら少なくとも職場で使われてるJavaのバージョンは調べた方が良いと思います(それと先のQiita記事の上司のような反応をされるかもしれないから、上司にも話した方が良いかと)。

@Lamron さん
コメントありがとうございます。eclipseで実装するときもJava11を使うようにします。
上司にも伝えて賛同は得られているので問題ございません。ご心配いただきありがとうございます。
